# Something wrong with the AppCenter updates

Tags: release-loki

I can't update just simple grow the file quantity (file size) higher and higher. What is the problem? "Waiting for package manager lock" This is the message.
1.7 GB the size and it's keep rising.

Comment: Reboot, open a terminal and execute this: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade ` . It seems that you didn't update your system for a long time so you have lots of files to download...

Answer (score 1):

Reboot, open a terminal and execute this: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` . It seems that you didn't update your system for a long time so you have lots of files to download...